# Entity Change Tracking in Dynamics 365 8.2 (On Premise)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Is Entity Change Tracking supported in version 8.2 on-premise?
I couldn't find an actual article from Microsoft that confirms this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use change tracking to synchronize data with external systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2015/developers-guide/dn932130(v=crm.7))

> For Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online organizations, this feature is available only if your organization has updated to Dynamics CRM Online 2015 Update 1. **This feature is not available for Dynamics CRM (on-premises)**.